# PostgreSql Ограничить вывод повторяющихся строк( 1 колонка разная), distinct не работает

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В таблице повторяются instagram_profile_id, в запросе тоже выводит несколько строк. distinct не работает так как created_at разный. Как мне вывести любую из этих строк, но одну?

Выполняю такой запрос:

```
select distinct instagram_account_followers.instagram_profile_id, "follower_count" 
from "instagram_profiles" 
inner join "instagram_account_followers" on "instagram_profiles"."id" = "instagram_account_followers"."instagram_profile_id" 
where "instagram_account_followers"."instagram_account_id" = ? 
  and "instagram_profile_id" not in (select distinct "instagram_profile_id" 
                                     from "instagram_account_followers" 
                                     where ("instagram_account_id" = ? 
                                       and "created_at" >= ? and "created_at" < ?)
                                    ) 
order by "follower_count" desc limit 10
```

вот скрин таблиц
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `distinct on (instagram_profile_id)` ?

Comment: @Ep1demic обновил вопрос

Comment: *distinct не работает так как created_at разный. Как мне вывести любую из этих строк, но одну?* Раз всё равно, что в created_at выводить - значит, можно его вообще не выводить. Значит, выбросить его нафиг из выходного набора. А заодно и DISTINCT заработает... Не нравится? добавить GROUP BY по всем остальным полям, а это created_at обернуть, например, в MAX().

Comment: Кстати... а в запросе-то как бы и нет этого поля, которое created_at ...

Comment: почему-то у меня дублирует строки

Comment: @akina, если я использую group by, то он просит добавить created_at в group by. может, из-за того, что join?

Comment: Из какой таблицы "падает" в выходной набор поле `follower_count`? Если DISTINCT в выходном наборе не удаляет дубликаты по instagram_profile_id - значит, оба поля берутся из instagram_account_followers. И, значит, там имеются несколько разных записей с совпадающим instagram_profile_id  - но тогда я в принципе не понимаю, какие тут дубли. А вообще - Вы бы лучше сформулировали задачу, а не свои попытки её решать... как положено, со структурой таблиц (а не фотографиями на тему) и примером исходных данных...